# How to resize ImageView by java code for Android

Tags: android

How to resize ImageView by java code when I press the Image ?

this my xml

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/MyPic"
            android:src="@drawable/clean"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
             />
```

and this my java

```
public class see_me extends Activity  {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.see_me);

 MyPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.MyPic);
```

Comment: Be more specific. Do you want to scale-animate the ImageView? Or make it instantly double-sized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resize image like below.

```
MyPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.MyPic);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
MyPic .setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Please this time don't forget to tick it answer.